# Complex query SQL, with nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I tried to solve the following exercise:

```
TEACHER(TeacherID, FirstNamme,LastName,Department)
COURSE(CourseID,CourseName,Year,Semester,TeacherID,Language)
STUDENT(StudentID,FirstName,LastName,BirthDate,Nationality)
STUDENT-COURSE-ENROLLMENT(CourseID,StudentID,EnrollmentYear)
STREAMING-VIDEOLECTURE(VideolevtureID,CourseID,Topic,Date,DurationMintes,TeacherID)
STREAMING-VIDEOLECTURE-ATTENDANCE(StudentID,VideLectoreID,CurseID,AttendaceInMinutes)
```

> Write in SQL.
> For each student enrolled in at least 3 courses in the 2019-2020 enrollment year,select the student ID and last name, and the ID of each course fro which the student attended all streaming video-lectures of the course.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: typically, returning a resultset from a relational database involves a SQL statement starting with the `SELECT` keyword, and referencing a row source (e.g. a table) in the `FROM` clause ...  from the question that is asked here, it's not at all clear where we need to start.  Do you have *any* query that retrieves rows?  For example, a query that retrieves rows from STUDENT-COURSE-ENROLLMENT ? How far did you get?  (StackOverflow is a question/answer resource, not a repository for "please do my homework for me" requests.

Comment: select studentID,lastName,count(courseID) from Student,Course,Student-course-enrollment where student.studentid=student-course-enrollment.studentID andstudent-course-enrollment.courseid=course.courseid and enrollmentYear= 2019 or enrollmentYear=2020.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  select s.FirstName,s.LastName ,sva.CurseID 
   from student s ,STREAMING-VIDEOLECTURE-ATTENDANCE  sva 
   where  s.StudentID  = sva.student_id  
   and  s.StudentID in (select ilv.student_id
                         from (select count(*),student_id 
                                from STUDENT-COURSE-ENROLLMENT
                                where EnrollmentYear between 2019 and 2020
                                group by student_id 
                                having count(*)>3 )ilv)
```